# How can i get all assets from my smart Contract

Tags: web3js, ether

I want to know what all assets are present in my smart contract using code ?

Comment: Post your Smart Contract code here, and reword your quesion

Comment: I have a smart contract containing different tokens i want to know which assets are present in that contract